# Problems Loading 32 bit .bmp texture in opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, alpha, bmp

I'm having some trouble loading a 32 bit .bmp image in my opengl game. So far i can load and display 24 bit perfectly. I now want to load a bit map with portions of its texture being transparent or invisible.

This function has no problems with 24 bit. but 32 bit with alpha channel .bmp seem to distort the colors and cause transparently in unintended places.

```
Texture LoadTexture( const char * filename, int width, int height, bool alpha) 
    {
        GLuint texture;
        GLuint* data;
        FILE* file;

        fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb");  
        if(!file)
        {
            std::cout << filename <<": Load Texture Fail!\n";
            exit(0);
        }

        data = new GLuint[width * height];

        fread( data, width * height * sizeof(GLuint), 1, file ); 
        fclose(file);

        glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        if(alpha) //for .bmp 32 bit
        {
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        }
        else //for .bmp 24 bit
        {
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4); 
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        }

        std::cout<<"Texture: "<<filename<< " loaded"<<std::endl;
        delete data;

        return Texture(texture); 
    }
```

In Game Texture, drawn on a flat plane
[image]

this might look like its working but the 0xff00ff color is the one that should be transparent. and if i reverse the alpha channel in photoshop the result is the same the iner sphere is always transparent.

i also enabled:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

there is no problems with transparency the problems seems to be with loading the bitmap with an alpha channel. also all bit maps that I load seem to be off a bit to the right. Just wondering if there was a reason for this?

Comment: Is it an actual BMP file?  You don't seem to be dealing with the header and such at the beginning before the pixel data.

Comment: no the image format is .bmp. is this what your asking?

Comment: Is it a raw array of pixels saved to disk and just named something.bmp, or is it an actual bmp format file such as what you would get if you saved an image as bmp from Photoshop, Gimp, etc.?  If it is the second, then there's a header you need to parse to know where to seek before reading the actual pixels.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: I had a problem like this a while back.  First I wrote a func that would write out a full .bmp file by hand and another func that would load it back in and use it.  Then, whenever I tried the same loader with a file from GIMP or PS, my colors would be inverted unless I used a different byte order enum or swizzled the bits.  Save out a solid color file and check the bytes themselves in a raw view text editor to debug your problem, that is, if I am understanding your problem right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this on the assumption that your file "parsing" is in-fact correct. That the file data is just the image part of a .BMP without any of the header information.

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

I find it curious that your 3-component data is in `BGR` order, yet your 4-component data is in `RGBA` order. Especially if this data comes from a .BMP file (though they don't allow alpha channels). Are you sure that your data isn't in a different ordering? For example, perhaps `ABGR` order?

Also, *stop using numbers for image formats*. You should use a [real, *sized* internal format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) for your textures, not "3" or "4".

Answer (score 0):

So code that i use work for 100% for me compiled by visual c 2012

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE); //Thia is very important!!!!
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  imag_ptr,  ptr->image->height, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imag_ptr);
```

and than in render i use

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0,0,0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glColor4ub(255,255,255,255);  //This is veryveryvery importent !!!!!!!!!!! (try to play and you see)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord3d(1,  1,  0);
glVertex2f(8,8);
glTexCoord3d(0,  1,  0);
glVertex2f(-8,8);
glTexCoord3d(0,  0,  0);
glVertex2f(-8,-8);
glTexCoord3d(1,  0,  0);
glVertex2f(8,-8);
glEnd();
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

and i use for example android png icon and another i try to post another image but i have no peputation for this so if you want i send it to you

So all of this in png format
but in bmp format and tga you must swap colors from ARGB to RGBA without this its not working

```
for( x=0;x<bmp_in_fheader.width;x++)
    {
        t=pixel[i];
        t1=pixel[i+1];
        t2=pixel[i+2];
        t3=pixel[i+3];

        pixel_temp[j]=t2;
        pixel_temp[j+1]=t1;
        pixel_temp[j+2]=t;
        pixel_temp[j+3]=t3;

        i+=4;
        j+=4;
    }
```

==Next==
To crate them in photoshop you must delete your background and draw on new layer than add alpha layer
in channels REMEMBER !! Very important to that in alpha all black color is represent transparency
and your image must be under white color only